# What are the items that go in the slot next to the spell?

Tags: rogue-legacy

Twice I've prayed at a statue and received an item that went into the blank slot next to my spell. It only lasts for that run, and I can't find any way to see what it does. What all items are available, and what do they do?

So far I've found:

- Hermes Boots
- Helios ?????
- Calypso's Compass
- Hyperion's Ring

Comment: I got one called "hedgehog's curse" which made gold fly out of me every time I took damage...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Hermes Boots**

Allows you to walk on spikes.

**Charon's Obol**

Next time you can enter castle for free.

**Hyperion Ring**

Gives you an extra life. When you die you come back to life with 25% HP health.

**Hedgehog's Curse**

You drop coins when hurt, a reference to Sonic the Hedgehog.

**Calypso's Compass**

Compass appears at the top of the screen, pointing to a hidden location. The location is a hidden door that has chests inside.

**Nerd Glasses**

- Corrects Near/far-sightedness
- Makes you see invisble items
- Cures color blindness
- Removes effect of vertigo and nostalgic traits
- Allows you to see the winning chest in the 3-chest gamble game

**Helios' Blessing**

Much greater chance and quantity of gold dropping from enemies (Does not affect chests.)

Found these on the [wiki](http://rogue-legacy.wikia.com/wiki/Special_Items), I'll be adding more of them once i find them myself or see people talk about them on forums.

Comment: According to [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/123482/2578) the nerd glasses also tell you which chest is the winner in the chest game.

Comment: Yeah, and i missed mentioning that it removes effects of nostalgia. Added those now.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered one so far:

**Hyperion's Ring**: When you die, brings you back to life with low health.