# Is the random chest game riggable?

Tags: rogue-legacy

Observe:
[image]

I've encountered a rather shady character who is willing to let me open a single chest, out of three, all for the mere cost of 25% of my coin.

Winning is worth triple my cost, so it's very much in my best interest to have much more coin, especially if I can determine which is the winning chest.

Is there a way to determine which chest is the winner?

Comment: I thought minors weren't allowed to gamble!

Comment: The good news here, btw, is that in two cases you'll lose your bet, and in the third case you'll win back your bet and twice more, so from a probabilistic standpoint your expected gain is zero.  In the long run, it makes no difference whether you play this game or not -- so, are you feeling lucky?

Comment: Jim is technically correct, that the expected gain is zero - however at later stages of the game, when upgrades start becoming really expensive, every coin is basically worthless until you get enough to afford an upgrade. I'd say it's in your best interest to gamble like a madman everytime you come across this guy!

Answer (score 15):

If you get the nerdy glasses from a shrine, the true chest is revealed. The only way I have seen that you can get the glasses if you have some sort of vision defect on the character.

Answer (score 10):

As Renderless said, the Nerdy Glasses will show you the correct chest. However, Calypso's Compass will show you the correct chest, as well.

In addition, there's another way to improve your expected payout with this game. The winning chest will produce coins/sacks/diamonds such that the total **base** value is triple what you paid. However, if you have any form of "Bounty" effect active (the Bounty effect is the game's term for any effect that increases the value of coins), the money from the winning chest is multiplied, as well! Ex: If you have $1000 when you play, you will lose $250. If you win, then money items totaling $750 base value (1 diamond, 2 bags, and 5 coins) will appear from the chest. If you have a Bounty of 100%, however, then the total value will be $1500.

Comment: How will Calypso's Compass show me the correct chest?

Comment: @frank It should point at the correct chest. However, looking at the wiki, it's no longer mentioned. Thus, it may not occur in the current version.

Comment: I just tried it, using the Compass, and can confirm that it doesn't  give any indication.

Answer (score -2):

As a spelunker on the large map, the `?` icon will be on top of the correct chest, or at least it's been the two times I've managed to find the place while a spelunker.

Comment: That's sheer coincidence.  The ? will always be in the center of the room.

Answer (score -3):

the miner upgrade, spelunker, can see the good chest

Comment: This isn't a very descriptive answer.  Please improve it by adding more details and explanation.

Comment: How, pray tell, can it do that?  I've tried using the headlamp, and there's no difference that I can see.  You're going to need to provide more information if you want me to accept it.

Comment: There's no indication on the map or the minimap for the Spelunker either.