# Where are the rest of my blueprints?

Tags: rogue-legacy

I've found/bought the squire, knight and vampiric versions of all the equipment, but I cannot find any more blueprints. Where do I find the rest of them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

More blueprints are only available (or at least the spawn rate is low) in harder areas of the castle.

Not all equipment is available in the first play through of the game. You need to be on NG+ or beyond to find all of the best blueprints.

From my experience, in NG++ I was able to find the last tier of gear fairly quickly.

If you are having difficulty finding blueprints, try hunting mini-bosses, they have a higher chance of awarding chests that contain blue prints. You could also visit the *Spiritual Shrine* and hope for a *[Calypso's Compass](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/122009/30210)*

Comment: I don't get any more than the first column without going to NG+? Seems like a lot to be missing.

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk You should definitely be able to get the first two columns without too much grind. Check harder areas of the castles or minibosses.

Comment: Ahh they probably are in other areas then. I haven't gone to far into them.

Comment: You haven't gone much past the first quarter of the castle, and you expect to have all the blueprints? Patience, grasshopper.

Comment: @Amadeus9 Not ALL of them but at least more than just 3 for each slot. Now that I've explored more and leveled, I'm definitely finding plenty more though